# Add header and footer to an RTF file using c#

Tags: c#, .net, rtf

We have an MVC app that outputs RTF files based on templates (which themselves are RTF files).

The code that my colleague wrote uses `System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox` to convert text to RTF file (to be more excat it uses the `Rtf` property of `RichTextBox`). I was thinking of adding headers and footers to the template RTF files, but `RichTextBox` appears to remove those. Additionally some of the documents that we generate are composed of multiple templates (more often than not, a single template does not equal a single page and one template can be injected in the middle of another), so thats one more reason why including headers and footers in the templates would not work.

Is there any way to add headers and footer in C# to RTF documents created in the way described above?

I tried fishing something on the subject from the internet, but I wasn't able to find anything concrete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was searching for a library that could possibly solve my problem and I came across this one:
[.NET RTF Writer Library in C#](http://sourceforge.net/projects/netrtfwriter/)

The library itself doesn't exactly solve my problem on it's own, but the documents generated by it are easy to read and without all the crap Word would put into them. The demo for this library generates a document that has a header and a footer. The code of those two looks more or less like this:

```
{\header

{\pard\fi0\qd
This is a header
\par}

}

{\footer

{\pard\fi0\qc
{\fs30 
This is a footer
}\par}

}
```

I still need to figure out how to apply correct formating here, but that should be relatively easy to find. So, I can solve my initial problem by injecting the code above to the RTF code generated by `RichTextBox`. I'm not sure if the position of those two tags matters, but I guess I will find that out soon enough...

---

Here is the code that I use to inject the header and footer:

```
public string AddHeaderAndFooter(string rtf)
{
    // Open file that stores header and footer
    string headerCode = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/DocTemplates/header.txt"));
    // Inject header and footer code before the last "}" character
    return rtf.Insert(rtf.LastIndexOf('}') - 1, headerCode);
}
```

Note I have the header and footer in a static txt file, because it actually contains images in RTF readable format and that would be too big to put in the code. I haven't noticed any problems related to the fact that header and footer are defined at the end of the RTF file.